# ES6 `static get length()` is not inherited as expected

Tags: javascript, es6-class, javascript-inheritance

I'm having an issue with providing a static getter function for the `length` property of my ES6 class extends.
As it turns out the actual `Function.length` getter always takes precedence over my own implementation.

```
class Foo {
  static get value() {
    return 'Foo';
  }

  static get length() {
    return this.value.length;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static get value() {
    return `${super.value}Bar`;
  }
}

console.log(Foo.value, Foo.length);  //  'Foo', 3
console.log(Bar.value, Bar.length);  //  'FooBar', 0
```

In the example above, `Foo` does exactly what I expected it to do, `Bar` not so much. `Bar.value` does indeed return `'FooBar'`, but `Bar.length` being `0` surprised me.

It took me a while to realize where the `0` came from, as I fully expected it to be `6` (and would have understood `3` to some degree). 
As it turns out the `0` value provided by `Bar.length` is in fact the length of the `constructor` function of `Bar`, I realised this when wrote the same example in ES5 notation, there is a quick way to prove this though; simply add a `constructor` to `Bar`.

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor(a, b, c, d) {
    //  four configured parameters
  }

  static get value() {
    return `${super.value}Bar`;
  }
}

console.log(Foo.value, Foo.length);  //  'Foo', 3
console.log(Bar.value, Bar.length);  //  'FooBar', 4
```

There are ways around this:

- add the `static get length()` to all extends (not my idea of
  inheritance)
- use a different property name (e.g. `static get size()` works as intended, but is not a generally used property in JS)
- extend the base from a built-in class which has a working `length` (e.g. `class Foo extends Array {...}`) -

None of these are what I want to do if there's a more appropriate way to do this.

> So my question is; does anyone know a proper way to have a custom property override which is inherited as expected, or am I being too stubborn?

---

As mentioned, I figured out what went wrong by writing the class syntax to (what I believe) would be the ES5 equivalent, as it may be beneficial to other developers and may shed some light on how *I think* ES6 classes work I'll leave it here.
(If anyone has a tip on how to make this bit collapsable on Stackoverflow, feel free to edit/suggest)

### What I suppose is happening in ES5 syntax

I am aware ES6 classes are mostly syntactic sugar around the prototypal inheritance JS has, so what seems to happen for `Bar` is something like;

```
function Foo() {}
Object.defineProperties(Foo, {
  value: {
    configurable: true, 
    get: function() {
      return 'Foo';
    }
  },
  length: {
    configurable: true, 
    get: function() {
      return this.value.length;
    }
  }
});

function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo));
Object.defineProperties(Bar, {
  value: { 
    configurable: true, 
    get: function() { 
      return 'Bar' + Foo.value; 
    }
  }
});

console.log(Foo.value, Foo.length);  //  'Foo', 3
console.log(Bar.value, Bar.length);  //  'FooBar', 0
```

I would've expected the property descriptors of `Foo` to be taken into account, like:

```
function Bar() {}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo));
Object.defineProperties(Bar, Object.assign(
  //  inherit any custom descriptors
  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Foo),
  {
    configurable: true, 
    value: { 
      get: function() { 
        return 'Bar' + Foo.value;
      }
    }
  }
));


console.log(Foo.value, Foo.length);  //  'foo', 3
console.log(Bar.value, Bar.length);  //  'bar', 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About static members

Static members of an ES6 class are in fact members of the *function object* rather than its prototype object. Consider the following example, where I'll use regular methods instead of a getter, but the mechanics are identical to getters:

```
class Foo {
    static staticMethod() {
        return 'Foo static';
    }

    nonStaticMethod() {
        return 'Foo non-static';
    }
}
```

`staticMethod` will become a member of the constructor function object, whereas `nonStaticMethod` will become a member of that function object's prototype:

```
function Foo() {}

Foo.staticMethod = function() {
    return 'Foo static';
}

Foo.prototype.nonStaticMethod = function() {
    return 'Foo non-static';
}
```

If you want to run `staticMethod` from a `Foo` 'instance' you'll have to navigate to its `constructor` first, which is the function object where `staticMethod` is a member of:

```
let foo = new Foo();

foo.staticMethod(); // Uncaught TypeError: foo.staticMethod is not a function

// Get the static member either on the class directly
// (this works IF you know that Foo is foo's constructor)

Foo.staticMethod(); // > 'Foo static'


// this is the same, provided that neither 'prototype' nor
// 'prototype.constructor' has been overridden afterwards:

Foo.prototype.constructor.staticMethod(); // > 'Foo static'


// ...or by getting the prototype of foo
// (If you have to perform a computed lookup of an object's constructor)
// You'll want to perform such statements in a try catch though...

Object.getPrototypeOf(foo).constructor.staticMethod(); // > 'Foo static'
```

---

## `function.length`

All [functions have a `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) that tells you how many arguments that function accepts:

```
function Foo(a, b) {}
Foo.length; // > 2
```

So in your example, a prototype lookup for `Bar.length` to `Foo.length` will indeed never occur, since `length` is already found directly on `Bar`. A simple override will not work:

```
Foo.length = 3;
Foo.length; // still 2
```

That is because the property is non-writable. Let's verify with [getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo, 'length');
/*
    { 
        value: 0,
        writable: false,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true
    }
*/
```

Also, instead of the `value` getter you define, you can instead just use [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) to get the name of a function / class constructor:

```
Foo.name; // > 'Foo'
```

Let's use this to override the `length` property on `Foo`. We are still able to override `Foo.length` because the property *is configurable*:

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo, 'length', {
    get() {
        return this.name.length;
    }
});

Foo.length; // 3
```

---

## This is code bloat

It is highly undesirable to have to do this for each extending class, or define a static getter for each, which is equivalent to the code above. It is not possible to entirely override the behaviour without any decoration of the function objects of some sort. But since we know that classes are just syntactic sugar, and we are actually just dealing with objects and functions, writing a decorator is easy!

```
function decorateClasses(...subjects) {

    subjects.forEach(function(subject) {

        Object.defineProperty(subject, 'value', {
            get() {
                const superValue = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).value || '';

                return superValue + this.name;
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });

        Object.defineProperty(subject, 'length', {
            get() {
                return this.value.length;
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    })

}
```

This function accepts one or multiple objects, on which it will override the `length` property and set a `value` property. Both are *accessors* with a `get` method. `get value` explicitly performs prototype lookups, and then combines the results with the name of the function it belongs to. So, if we have 3 classes:

```
class Foo {

}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

class Baz extends Bar {

}
```

We can decorate all classes at once:

```
decorateClasses(Foo, Bar, Baz);
```

If we access `value` and `length` on all three classes (functions) we get the desired results:

```
Foo.value; // 'Foo'
Foo.length; // 3

Bar.value; // 'FooBar'
Bar.length; // 6

Baz.value; // 'FooBarBaz'
Baz.length; // 9
```

Comment: My problem is that the constructor function of `Bar` is not `Foo` but `Function` (as specified for ES6) but somehow all but the built-in static members of `Foo` do end up being available on `Bar`. So the issue is not that I can't get to the length, the issue is that `length` on `Bar` is not the `length` from `Foo` but from `Function`, if I rename it to `size` everything works as expected. I didn't expect this.

Comment: I see, I figured that a little too late. I'll see if I can think of a better answer. There are ways to do what you're trying to achieve, but that would require you to explicitly write your own implementation, since classes (and actually prototyping in general) does not provide you facilities to create the intended behaviour.

Comment: That's what I figured, I was hoping the SO community would know something I missed. If you put the "Classes do not provide this.." in your answer I'll accept it as the answer (until someone comes along with something that proves otherwise of course). Thank you for your time!

Comment: I further edited my answer for some more clarity. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: "An extends clause in JS will always only create a prototype link between `Foo.prototype` and `Bar.prototype`" is only half of what `extends` does. It also prototypes the constructor of extended class instances on the constructor of base class instances. `Object.getPrototypeOf( Bar) === Foo` is true.

Comment: @Traktor53 Then my answer is not right. Would you mind editing?

Comment: I already removed all wrong info and updated the answer. I completely misunderstood the question at first...

Comment: Good work. Given that the static member names which can't be automatically inherited are the local property names of a function object ( `prototype`, `length` and `name`) and `prototype` is read only for class constructors, avoiding their use as member names remains tenable.